# Bash regexp: How to replace all non-whitespace characters with a letter?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a text file that contains a lot of whitespace and some other ASCII characters. I would like to use Bash (preferably via `sed`) to replace any non-whitespace characters in the file with the letter `M`. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks for helping.

**edit:** For the downvoters, I tried running this:

```
sed -i 's/[^\s]/M/g' file
```

and this:

```
sed -i 's/[^\s]/M/' file
```

but neither of them worked out too well. I'm a little unfamiliar with regex, so apologies if I'm doing something obviously wrong.

Comment: I'm reasonably certain `\s` is a Perl thing, and in Perl, you'd use `\S` instead of `[^\s]` to match non-whitespace characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use POSIX character classes:

```
sed -i 's/[^[:space:]]/M/g' file
```

For example:

```
$ echo 'a b       c' | od -a                  
0000000   a  sp   b  sp  ht   c  nl
0000007
$ echo 'a b       c' | sed 's/[^[:space:]]/M/g' | od -a
0000000   M  sp   M  sp  ht   M  nl
0000007
```

Note:

- The `g` flag to the `s` command, since you want to replace all matches in a line

Comment: muru, thanks for helping! The question says **non**-whitespace characters, however.

Comment: OP is asking for **non-whitespace** characters. The opposite character class to [[:space:]] should be used.

Comment: @RanyAlbegWein ... which is `[^[:space:]]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use tr

```
tr -c '[:space:]' M < file
```